# How to link to next page url in handleSubmit formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, formik

I have two functional components in my process. First, I need the first component info to be filled and validated by Formik and Yup and then user can process the next step in the second component by click Next. For now, I can get everything validated and code can reach on handleSubmit() without any problem. But, the problem is that, I could not link to another component using `<Link>`. I have tried:

```
 // Using this first one, no validation is performed and it will link to another component directly
 <Link to="/Next">
    <button type="submit">Next</Button>
 </Link>


 // I have put these inside handleSubmit() but it is undefined.
 this.context.router.push('/Next');
 Router.push('/Next')
 this.props.history.push('/Next')
```

Mostly I got undefined output on console using these code. It's seems like that i could not access props from functional components like i could in the react class. Here is my first component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withFormik, Field } from 'formik';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    Switch,
    Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";


const MyForm = props => { const {handleSubmit} = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <button type="submit">Next</button>
//          <Link to="/Next">
//              <button type="submit">Next</Button>
//          </Link>
    </Field>
  );
};

const MyEnhancedForm = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ email: '' }),

  handleSubmit: (values, formikBag) => {
      // Link to next page code
  },
})(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can't use this.props in functional components but what we can do is that write the same routing logic in parent component and pass it as a prop in the functional component.
Then we can call the same function in `handleSubmit()`.

Comment: Seem like a good idea. I have never thought of this and i always wanted to get "props" or "this", but could not find any answer for this one. You have shine a light now. I will try.

Comment: currently, i passed "this" and "this.props" from parent to the  first functional component child and i tried to access its history property using "parent.history" but it still undefined. I have console.log(parent) and i got: 
`_dispatchInstances: Object { tag: 5, elementType: "button", type: "button", … }
​

_targetInst: Object { tag...
​
altKey: false
​
bubbles: true
​
button: 0
​
buttons: 0
​
cancelable: true
​
clientX: 1246
​
clientY: 339
​
ctrlKey: false
​

​
defaultPrevented: false
​
detail: 1
​
view: Window.....` I could not find history property at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hooks you can follow the approach described in this blog post https://dev.to/httpjunkie/programmatically-redirect-in-react-with-react-router-and-hooks-3hej in order to programmatically redirect with react-router and hooks. A summary:

Include `useState` in your imports:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Inside your functional component add:

```
const [toNext, setToNext] = useState(false)
```

Inside `handleSubmit` add:

```
setToNext(true)
```

Inside the `<form>` add:

```
{toNext ? <Redirect to="/Next" /> : null}
```